# Hamiltonian Expectation Value for a Non-Local Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics

For a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ where the potential energy operator $\hat{V}$ is local, the expectation value of $\hat{H}$ with respect to a momentum space state ket $|\phi_p\rangle$ is given by

$$ \langle \phi_p |\hat{H} |\phi_p\rangle = \langle \phi_p |\hat{T} |\phi_p\rangle  + \langle \phi_p |\hat{V} |\phi_p\rangle $$

where $\hat{T}$ is the kinetic energy operator, $\langle p | \phi_p\rangle = \phi_p(\textbf{p})$ and $V = V(\textbf{p})$ is a local potential function in 
momentum space.

But I am confused about the expression of the expectation value of $\hat{H}$ for a non-local potential function $V = V(\textbf{p}, \textbf{p}')$  in momentum space. **Should it be the same?** That is,

$$ \langle \phi_p |\hat{H} |\phi_p\rangle = \langle \phi_p |\hat{T} |\phi_p\rangle  + \langle \phi_p |\hat{V} |\phi_p\rangle $$

so that

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle \phi_p |\hat{V} |\phi_p\rangle &=& \int \langle \phi_p |p'\rangle\langle  p' |\hat{V}(\textbf{p}, \textbf{p}') |p\rangle\langle  p|\phi_p\rangle \, dp \, dp' \\
&=& \int \phi_p (\textbf{p}') \langle  p' |\hat{V}(\textbf{p}, \textbf{p}') |p\rangle \phi_p (\textbf{p}) \, dp \, dp'.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I've never heard of a "non local" potential.. would you mind linking something to define this or just define it in the question

Comment: @InertialObserver Please have a look at page no. 8 of this pdf: https://www.phys.ksu.edu/personal/wysin/notes/qmcurrent.pdf . I am sorry for replying so late.